# Замена встроенного клиента RDP

Tags: windows, rdp

Какие есть качественные варианты помимо встроенного клиента Windows для удаленного подключения? Я пробовал [Royal TS](http://www.code4ward.net/main/): в целом неплохо, но особых преимуществ нет.

Comment: Замена клиента RDP или замена вообще для всех технологии RDP?

Comment: Сам клиент. То, что дает Windows, - это необходимый минимум, возможно, есть что-то более удобное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хочется поменять сам **клиент**, то вот неплохой бесплатный вариант [mRemote](http://www.mremote.org/wiki/Overview.ashx). Помимо RDP поддерживается VNС, SSH и тп.